# Flutter and TFlite Plugin Real-time Image Classification Image Preprocessing

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, camera, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

I created a real-time image classification application that detects objects and produces results in real-time. This is all possible because of the "runModelOnFrame" of the flutter tflite plugin that I used. However, I want to preprocess or resize the images/frames captured by the live camera preview to 224x224 first before the model shows the results on the screen because I trained my dataset images to 224x224, and the live camera preview is in full screen size. I am stuck on how to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: You can also [firebase ML kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/use-custom-models) now to use tflite models

Answer (score 0):

tflite flutter plugin provides helper plugin that can do that in sequence. look at the exmaple